# How to convert timestamp?

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion.

I get data from a Rails 3.2.8 API and I want to convert the timestamp I get (`2013-01-24T23:42:59Z`) to `2013-01-24 23:42:59`. How can I do that with Ruby?

What is this format called (`2013-01-24T23:42:59Z`)?

Comment: Do you mean printing a String from a timestamp formatted like `2013-01-24 23:42:59`?

Comment: I need to convert this: 2013-01-24T23:42:59Z into this 2013-01-24 23:42:59. Simple loose the T and the Z.

Comment: By the way, I would recommend upgrading your Rails 3.2.8 to Rails 3.2.11 -- there are some very significant security issues in 3.2.10 and before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is called ISO 8601. You can accept this form and turn it into a time object by doing this:

```
require "time"
Time.iso8601("2013-01-24T23:42:59Z")
# => 2013-01-24 23:42:59 UTC
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I loose the UTC part?

Comment: Play around with [`Time#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

Comment: That is not available in Rubymotion unfortunately.

Comment: Wrongo - [`Time#strftime`](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/Time.html#strftime-instance_method) *IS* available in Rubymotion. Scroll down to the ["Various ISO 8601 formats"](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Time#strftime-instance_method) section in Ruby's `strftime` documentation to see how to build the ISO-8601 formats from the `strftime` primitives.